# in numpy what is the multi dimensional equivalent of take

Tags: python, numpy

I have this bit of code

```
def build_tree_base(blocks, x, y, z):
   indicies = [
        (x  ,z  ,y  ),
        (x  ,z+1,y  ),
        (x  ,z  ,y+1),
        (x  ,z+1,y+1),
        (x+1,z  ,y  ),
        (x+1,z+1,y  ),
        (x+1,z  ,y+1),
        (x+1,z+1,y+1),
    ]
    children = [blocks[i] for i in indicies]
    return Node(children=children)
```

Where blocks is a 3 dimensional numpy array.

What I'd like to do is replace the list comprehension with something like numpy.take, however take seems to only deal with single dimension indices. Is there something like take that will work with multidimensional indices?

Also I know you could do this with a transpose, slice and then reshape, but that was slow so I'm looking for a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about taking a 2x2x2 slice, then `flat` ?

```
import numpy as np
blocks = np.arange(2*3*4.).reshape((2,3,4))
i,j,k = 0,1,2
print [x for x in blocks[i:i+2, j:j+2, k:k+2].flat]
```

(`flat` is an iterator; expand it like this, or with `np.fromiter()`,
or let Node iter over it.)

Answer (score 2):

Numpy indexing make this quite easy... You should be able to to something like this:

```
def build_tree_base(blocks, x, y, z):
    idx = [x, x, x, x, x+1, x+1, x+1, x+1]
    idz = [z, z+1, z, z+1, z, z+1, z, z+1]
    idy = [y, y, y+1, y+1, y, y, y+1, y+1]
    children = blocks[idx, idz, idy]
    return Node(children=children)
```

Edit: I should point out that this (or any other ["fancy" indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2)) will return a copy, rather than a view into the original array...

Comment: the good news is it worked, so I've learnt something new about numpy, the bad news is it is much slower

Comment: With a small array, it will be. With a larger one, it will be much, much faster than a list comprehension (though it will use more memory). Try making `idx`, etc numpy arrays with `dtype=np.int`. (E.g. `idx = np.array([x,x...], dtype=np.int)`) It might help with the overhead of small arrays....

Comment: I should also point out that if you're doing this on a huge number of tiny numpy arrays, you should probably re-think your data structure. Numpy is _very_ well suited to large arrays, but the overhead of array creation will dominate if you're using numerous tiny arrays. In that case, native python types (or views into a single, large numpy array) are a better choice.